# Help Solving for 'y' when 'y' is in numerator and denominator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm taking a differential equations college course, and I'm embarrassed to say that I'm a bit hung up on some algebra with a particular problem. I'm having issues getting an implicit solution into explicit form by hand.

$\frac{y-2}{y+2}=\pm ce^{4x}$

My algebra skills are extremely rusty, and I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure out how to solve this equation explicitly for $y$. I can get a solution on my calculator, but I would prefer to understand how to come to the solution by hand. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to add a comment, note that all solutions below automatically excluded $y=-2$ (which is the case for the fraction to be undefined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $$\pm ce^{4x}=r$$ then we have
$$\frac{y-2}{y+2}=r$$ multiplying by $y+2$ we get
$$y-2=r(y+2)$$
$$y-2=ry+2r$$
$$y-ry=2+2r$$
$$y(1-r)=2(1+r)$$
$$y=\frac{2(1+r)}{1-r}$$
back substituion of $r$ gives the searched result

Comment: Thank You, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{y-2}{y+2}=\pm ce^{4x}\\
\frac{y+2-4}{y+2}=\pm ce^{4x}\\
1-\frac{4}{y+2}=\pm ce^{4x}\\
1-\pm ce^{4x}=\frac4{y+2}\\
\frac1{1-\pm ce^{4x}}=\frac{y+2}4\\
\frac4{1-\pm ce^{4x}}=y+2\\
\frac4{1 \mp ce^{4x}}-2=y\\
y = \frac{2\pm2ce^{4x}}{1\mp ce^{4x}}$$